# How do I reuse the SplitWhitespace iterator?

Tags: rust

I've got a piece of code which is supposed to check if two sentences are "too similar", as defined by a heuristic made clearest by the code.

```
fn too_similar(thing1: &String, thing2: &String) -> bool {
    let split1 = thing1.split_whitespace();
    let split2 = thing2.split_whitespace();

    let mut matches = 0;
    for s1 in split1 {
        for s2 in split2 {
            if s1.eq(s2) {
                matches = matches + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    let longer_length =
        if thing1.len() > thing2.len() {
            thing1.len()
        } else {
            thing2.len()
        };

    matches > longer_length / 2
}
```

However, I'm getting the following compilation error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `split2`
 --> src/main.rs:7:19
  |
7 |         for s2 in split2 {
  |                   ^^^^^^ value moved here in previous iteration of loop
  |
  = note: move occurs because `split2` has type `std::str::SplitWhitespace<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I'm not sure why `split2` is getting moved in the first place, but what's the Rust way of writing this function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`split2` is getting moved because iterating with `for` consumes the iterator and since the type does not implement `Copy`, Rust isn't copying it implicitly.

You can fix this by creating a new iterator inside the first `for`:

```
let split1 = thing1.split_whitespace();

let mut matches = 0;
for s1 in split1 {
    for s2 in thing2.split_whitespace() {
        if s1.eq(s2) {
            matches = matches + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
...
```

You can also rewrite the `matches` counting loop using some higher order functions available in the `Iterator` trait:

```
let matches = thing1.split_whitespace()
    .flat_map(|c1| thing2.split_whitespace().filter(move |&c2| c1 == c2))
    .count();
```

`longer_length` can also be written as:

```
let longer_length = std::cmp::max(thing1.len(), thing2.len());
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and a way to get around this. Shouldn't `SplitWhitespace` be copyable, then? Seems inefficient to have to split on each word.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18045 explains why `SplitWhitespace` doesn't implement `Copy`. Also, this won't be any slower than if `SplitWhitespace` implemented `Copy` since iterators are lazy and creating a `SplitWhitespace` struct has negligible overhead compared to the time taken to iterate through the splits.

Comment: It is surprising it doesn't implement `Clone` though.

Answer (score 2):

There are possibly some better ways to do the word comparison.

If the phrases are long, then iterating over `thing2`'s words for every word in `thing1` is not very efficient.  If you don't have to worry about words which appear more than once, then `HashSet` may help, and boils the iteration down to something like:

```
let words1: HashSet<&str> = thing1.split_whitespace().collect();
let words2: HashSet<&str> = thing2.split_whitespace().collect();
let matches = words1.intersection(&words2).count();
```

If you do care about repeated words you probably need a `HashMap`, and something like:

```
let mut words_hash1: HashMap<&str, usize> = HashMap::new();
for word in thing1.split_whitespace() {
    *words_hash1.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1;
}
let matches2: usize = thing2.split_whitespace()
                     .map(|s| words_hash1.get(s).cloned().unwrap_or(0))
                     .sum();
```